# Creating an ArrayList containing only specified pixels

Tags: java, image-processing, arraylist

I'm loading a BufferedImage and getting RGB values for the pixels based on their xy location.
After I would like to create an ArrayList containing only  the black pixels.
I'm trying to create the list doing this:

```
List<Integer> blackpixels = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

but I get this error at the line where I declare the list:

The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

Here's my full code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.List;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.*;


public class ImageTest {
    public static BufferedImage Threshold(BufferedImage img) {

        int height = img.getHeight();
        int width = img.getWidth();
        BufferedImage finalImage = new BufferedImage(width,height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        int r = 0;
        int g = 0;
        int b = 0;
        List<Integer> blackpixels = new ArrayList<Integer>();



        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
//          System.out.println("Row: " + x);
            try {

                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {

                    //Get RGB values of pixels
                    int rgb = img.getRGB(x, y); 
                    r = ImageTest.getRed(rgb);
                    g = ImageTest.getGreen(rgb);
                    b = ImageTest.getBlue(rgb);


                    finalImage.setRGB(x,y,ImageTest.mixColor(r, g,b));  
                    System.out.println(r);
                }

                }
            catch (Exception e) {
                    e.getMessage();
            }
    }
    return finalImage;

    }
    private static int mixColor(int red, int g, int b) {
        return red<<16|g<<8|b;
    }

    public static int getRed(int rgb) {
        return (rgb & 0x00ff0000)  >> 16;
    }

    public static int getGreen(int rgb) {
        return  (rgb & 0x0000ff00)  >> 8;
    }

    public static int getBlue(int rgb) {
        return (rgb & 0x000000ff)  >> 0;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you are getting, is that the `List` you are trying to create comes from `java.awt.List` instead of `java.util.List`. If you are not going to use the `java.awt.List`, just remove the

```
import java.awt.List;
```

You are already importing the correct class with `import java.util.*;`, so after removing the mentioned sentence it should work properly.